# How to find expiration date for SharePoint 2013 trial version?

Tags: 2013, expiration

I have a trial version of SharePoint 2013 installed. Where can I find the expiration date of my trial version. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trial version is valid for 180 days. So you can find the installed date by opening

Control Panel -> Programs -> Program and Features

And look for the installed date on "Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013"